# Merging Duplicate records in Crystal Report 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I am working with a windows application having front end in vb.net and back end ms access 2007
In ms access 2007  I have following tables with data:

```
MeetingDetails Table
ID  MeetingNo   SubjectId   MeetingSubject  Instructions                    Status
1      1         A001      Human Resource   All Recruitments must be completed till April 2016  
Incomplete
2      2         A001       Human Resource  All Recruitments must be completed till June 2016   Inprocess
3      3         A001       Human Resource  All Recruitments must be completed till August 2016 Inprocess
4      4         A001       Human Resource  All Recruitments must be completed till September 2016  Complete

Subject Table
Subjectid   SubjectName
A001      Human Resource
A002      Infrastructure
A003      IT
A004      Planning
```

I am printing this records in crystal reports in vb.net 2010 like this by using lines for designing(drawing object)

```
ID  MeetingSubject  Instructions                                        Status
1   Human Resource  All Recruitments must be completed till April 2016  complete
2   Human Resource  All Recruitments must be completed till June 2016   Inproces
3   Human Resource  All Recruitments must be completed till August 2016 Inproces
4   Human Resource  All Recruitments must be completed till Sept 2016   Complete
```

But I want to print this records like this  with no repetition of lines and duplicate data:

```
ID  MeetingSubject  Instructions                                         Status
1                   All Recruitments must be completed till April2016 Incomplete
2                   All Recruitments must be completed till June2016   Inprocess
3   Human Resource  All Recruitments must be completed till August2016 Inprocess
4                   All Recruitments must be completed till Sept2016    Complete
```

I want to merge duplicate records into one records , also lines. Please help me.

Comment: Try posting the SQL that is being used

Answer (score 0):

Create a group for meeting subject and rest of the field in detail section.